# Некорректная фильтрация строки

Tags: c++, строки, циклы

Имеется код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string str = "Hallow, world";
    int i = 0;
    for (i; i < str.length(); i++) {
        if (str[i] == ',') {
            str.erase(i);
        };
    };
    cout << str;
    return 0;
}
```

Цикл завершается тогда, когда условие впервые принимает значение "истина", хотя цикл должен продолжаться до конечного символа строки. Почему так происходит?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Правильно удалять так:

```
for (; i < str.length();) {
    if (str[i] == ',')
        str.erase(i, 1);
    else
        i++;
};
```

Таким образом вы удаляете каждый раз по одному символу. Кроме того, при удалении символы сдвигаются, так что вам нужно перепроверить текущий индекс. Поэтому `i++` ушло в `else`. (Кроме того, в таком виде `for` можно заменить на `while`.)

Более идиоматический метод удаления из строки в C++ — использование `<algorithm>` и идиомы erase/remove:

```
str.erase(std::remove(str.begin(), str.end(), ','), str.end());
```

или, если хочется более сложного условия,

```
str.erase(std::remove_if(str.begin(), str.end(), [](char x){ return x == ','; }), str.end());
```

(Спасибо @Vlad from Moscow за уточнение!)

Answer (score 6):

Наверно по тому, что `erase()` удаляет часть строки начиная с позиции i, в результате str.length() уменьшается и становится равным 6, что меньше значения i равного 7. Условие в цикле становится ложным и он завершается.